# Why does one file object flush, but the other one doesn't?

Tags: python, file, flush

I wanted a file object that flushes out straight to file as data is being written, and wrote this:

```
class FlushingFileObject(file):
    def write(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return_val= file.write(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.flush()
        return return_val

    def writelines(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return_val= file.writelines(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.flush()
        return return_val
```

but interestingly it doesn't flush as I write to it, so I tried a few things including this:

```
class FlushingFileObject(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.file_object= file(*args,**kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.file_object,item)

    def write(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return_val= self.file_object.write(*args,**kwargs)
        self.file_object.flush()
        return return_val

    def writelines(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return_val= self.file_object.writelines(*args,**kwargs)
        self.file_object.flush()
        return return_val
```

which does flush.

Why doesn't subclassing `file` work in this instance?

Comment: Could you show how do you test the flushing? Because both works correctly when I try them.

Comment: I actually assigned them to `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` and ran a program I have, and tailed the file. With the first one that subclasses file, the output only got written when I closed the program

Comment: Also a weird thing, it can't find `__exit__` attribute with the second object which I don't understand? I get an `AttributeError` when trying to use it with `with`

Comment: `__exit__` is the function called automatically by the runtime when code exits a [`with` statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).  Why it can't find it, I don't know, since it should invoke your `__getattr__` which in turn will call the file object's `__exit__`.  What version of Python are you running?

Comment: @Adam I'm running python 2.7.3- yea all other attributes seem to get forwarded on (even `__enter__`) but not exit for some reason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question.

This happens because Python optimizes calls to `write` on `file` objects by bypassing the Python-level `write` method and calling `fputs` directly.

To see this in action, consider:

```
$ cat file_subclass.py
import sys
class FileSubclass(file):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        raise Exception("write called!")
    writelines = write
sys.stdout = FileSubclass("/dev/null", "w")
print "foo"
sys.stderr.write("print succeeded!\n")
$ python print_magic.py
print succeeded!
```

The `write` method was never called!

Now, when the object isn't a subclass of `file`, things work as expected:

```
$ cat object_subclass.py
import sys
class ObjectSubclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        raise Exception("write called!")
    writelines = write
sys.stdout = ObjectSubclass()
print "foo"
sys.stderr.write("print succeeded!\n")
$ python object_subclass.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 13, in <module>
    print "foo"
  File "x.py", line 8, in write
    raise Exception("write called!")
Exception: write called!
```

Digging through the Python source a bit, it looks like the culprit is the `PyFile_WriteString` function, called by the `print` statement, which checks to see whether the object being written to is an instance of `file`, and if it is, bypasses the object's methods and calls `fputs` directly:

```
int
PyFile_WriteString(const char *s, PyObject *f)
{

    if (f == NULL) {
        /* … snip … */
    }
    else if (PyFile_Check(f)) { //-- `isinstance(f, file)`
        PyFileObject *fobj = (PyFileObject *) f;
        FILE *fp = PyFile_AsFile(f);
        if (fp == NULL) {
            err_closed();
            return -1;
        }
        FILE_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS(fobj)
        fputs(s, fp); //-- fputs, bypassing the Python object entirely
        FILE_END_ALLOW_THREADS(fobj)
        return 0;
    }
    else if (!PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyObject *v = PyString_FromString(s);
        int err;
        if (v == NULL)
            return -1;
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(v, f, Py_PRINT_RAW);
        Py_DECREF(v);
        return err;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to look at the python sources, but I can't find exactly where the "print" statement is defined. Anyway, I can see that `PyObject_Print` uses a `FILE` pointer, so maybe when print sees a file subclass it simply gets the `FILE` pointer from the structure and uses its write operation(thus it does not call the overridden method).

Comment: See `case PRINT_ITEM:` in `ceval.c` (line 1752 in version 2.7.2). But, yes, you are absolutely correct — see my edit for the details

Comment: In the first example you override the `__init__` which prevents the underlying `file` class from initializing properly. The `print` statement is hard-wired to call the `file.write` implementation if `stdout` successfully passes the "instance of file" test. That one in turn raises the `ValueError` because your subclass object is not initialized properly.

Comment: @patrys yes, exactly. Although… I suppose that example could be more obvious. Let me fix that up.

Comment: Great answer :). That explains a lot thanks! I guess it's all in the name of io optimisation but it was really confusing to see 2 almost identical objects behaving differently

Answer (score -1):

The documentation of `file.flush()` says:

Note
flush() does not necessarily write the file’s data to disk. Use flush() followed by os.fsync() to ensure this behavior.

I tested the first version of FlushingFileObject without the os.fsync call. The file did not flush. After inserting `os.fsync(self.fileno())` the file flushed. Then I removed the os.fsync call and now the file flushed ! I think to be sure, the os.fsync call is necessary.

Comment: The documentation you cite is not incorrect, but this is the incorrect answer to the question. See my answer.