# Why doesn't __getattr__ work with __exit__?

Tags: python, attr, with-statement

I came across this as a bit of a surprise while trying to work out another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627297/why-does-one-file-object-flush-but-the-other-one-doesnt).

This seemed extremely odd to me, I thought it was worth asking the question. Why doesn't `__getattr__` appear to work with `with`?

if I make this object:

```
class FileHolder(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.f= file(*args,**kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self,item):
        return getattr(self.f,item)
```

and using it with `with`,

```
>>> a= FileHolder("a","w")
>>> a.write
<built-in method write of file object at 0x018D75F8>
>>> with a as f:
...   print f
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
>>> a.__exit__
<built-in method __exit__ of file object at 0x018D75F8>
```

Why does this happen?

### EDIT

```
>>> object.__exit__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__exit__'
```

It definitely isn't inheriting `__exit__`

Comment: Something is going on here, in your class definition you make `FileHolder` a subclass of `object`.  But in your code below it, it says that `a` is a `file` object.  Thats not consistent.

Comment: @jedwards Honestly it isn't. Test it yourself :)

Comment: @jedwards, the `__exit__` is from the `file` object assigned to `self.f`, if you ask `type(a)`, you'll get `FileHolder`.

Comment: @Adam, you're right -- I actually didn't create the class (I did something like `class FileHolder(object): pass`) -- serves me right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but after reading over the PEP describing the with statement:

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

This jumped out at me:

```
A new statement is proposed with the syntax:

    with EXPR as VAR:
        BLOCK

....

The translation of the above statement is:

    mgr = (EXPR)
    exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
    value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)

....
```

Right there. The with statement does not call `__getattr__(__exit__)` but calls `type(a).__exit__` which does not exist giving the error.

So you just need to define those:

```
class FileHolder(object):                                                                                                                 
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.f= file(*args,**kwargs)

    def __enter__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return self.f.__enter__(*args,**kwargs)

    def __exit__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.f.__exit__(*args,**kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self,item):
        return getattr(self.f,item)
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the documentation is not-quite-right on this one -- special method lookup also ignores `type(x).__getattr__`. See my answer...

Comment: I can't say for sure. My only guess is it's that way by design. It might be something to ask on the mailing list.

Comment: @GP89: I did some more digging; it's by design. See [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) for the full reasoning.

Comment: I also did some digging in the mailing list @nneonneo mention. Here is a short summary: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-May/089576.html

Answer (score 6):

The `with` statement opcode `SETUP_WITH` looks up `__exit__` as a "special method lookup", which ignores `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` on new-style classes (but not on old-style classes). See [this mailing list thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-May/089535.html) for more information, where they discuss adding the special method lookup semantics to `with` (which they eventually do). See also [special method lookup for new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes) for a detailed discussion on why these special methods are looked up in this way.

In particular, special method lookup *also* bypasses `__getattr__` on the type object. So, even though the documentation says the method is looked up as `type(mgr).__exit__`, this code doesn't work:

```
class M(type):
    def __getattr__(*args): return lambda: 0

class X(object):
    __metaclass__ = M

x = X()
type(x).__exit__ # works, returns a lambda

with x: pass # fails, AttributeError
```

Comment: It does beg the question though, why does `__enter__` not get an `AttributeError`? unless it looks for exit first which seems unlikely

Comment: As @korylprince's answer indicates, `__exit__` is looked up first, so that they don't run into issues with calling `__enter__` without a functional `__exit__`. You can see the exact CPython implementation [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/198382b4bcd0/Python/ceval.c#l2545).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers has explained the fact that `__getattr__` does not work with `__enter__` and `__exit__`. I'm here to give my thinking of why it **SHOULD NOT** work.

The only reason we define `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods on an object is that we need to use it in `with` statement. The two methods help us get and release a resource implicitly, so we usually define them like this:

```py
class Resource(object):
    ...
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
            
    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.close()
```

then you can write some code like this:

```py
with Resource() as resource:  # __enter__ is called and returns a value as `resource`
    do_something_with_resource()
    # `resource.__exit__` is called
```

As you have noticed, the resource we get and release is exactly an instance of the class we defined.

What if we hold a resource as an attribute and proxy its `__enter__` and `__exit__` with `__getattr__`? We write some code like this:

```py
class ResourceProxy(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._resource = Resource()

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self._resource, key)
```

Assuming `__getattr__` works fine with `__enter__` and `__exit__`, here is what will happen in `with` statement:

```py
with ResourceProxy() as resource:  # proxied __enter__ is called
    # now `resource` is NOT a ResourceProxy instance, because what we called is `_resource.__enter__`
    do_something_with_resource()
    # `_resource.__exit__` is called and closed itself properly. 
    # Here is nothing to do with ResourceProxy, because it has never enter `with` context
```

The behavior above is strange and probably not as the user expected, for the following two reasons:

1. the resource entered into `with` context is not the object we sent in.
2. when exiting `with` context, `__exit__` method of the proxied object is called, instead of the outer object we sent in. You may think it might help if we add an `__exit__` definition on the outer class, but the answer is not, because the outer class has never enter `with` context.

To conclude, if we make `__getattr__` works with `__enter__` and `__exit__`, it will result in bad behaviors. It's not a good design.